# Joining inside subqueries - STUFF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please could you help me. I do something wrong.

```
SELECT        
    EventSpotsJoin.Event, Links.LongLat 
FROM 
    EventSpotsJoin 
INNER JOIN 
    Links ON EventSpotsJoin.Spot = Links.IdLinks 
ORDER BY 
    EventSpotsJoin.Event
```

Result is

```
2054    39.0440182, -74.7659984
2054    28.29555, -80.60898333333333
2068    39.0440182, -74.7659984
2068    28.29555, -80.60898333333333
```

And I would like to join lat long into one row. I use this code.

```
 SELECT 
     [EventSpotsJoin].[Event], 
     STUFF((SELECT '|' + CAST(Links.LongLat AS nvarchar) 
            FROM [dbo].[EventSpotsJoin]
            WHERE EventSpotsJoin.Spot = Links.IdLinks
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM            
    EventSpotsJoin 
INNER JOIN
    Links ON EventSpotsJoin.Spot = Links.IdLinks
ORDER BY 
    EventSpotsJoin.Event
```

and the result is wrong:

```
2054    39.0440182, -74.7659984|39.0440182, -74.7659984
2054    28.29555, -80.60898333333333|28.29555, -80.60898333333333
2068    39.0440182, -74.7659984|39.0440182, -74.7659984
2068    28.29555, -80.60898333333333|28.29555, -80.60898333333333
```

I need to group it by Event and join not the same lat long result.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :** Assuming That you are expecting out put for event id `2054` is `39.0440182, -74.7659984|28.29555, -80.60898333333333`

```
SELECT [EventSpotsJoin].[Event], STUFF(
     (SELECT '|' + CAST(Links.LongLat AS nvarchar) 
      FROM Links 
      WHERE EventSpotsJoin.Spot = Links.IdLinks
      FOR XML PATH (''))
     , 1, 1, '')
FROM EventSpotsJoin 
ORDER BY EventSpotsJoin.Event
```

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting exactly what you said. But result is still wrong :( Every lat long is in separate row. 

2054 39.0440182, -74.7659984

2054 28.29555, -80.60898333333333

2068 39.0440182, -74.7659984

2068 28.29555, -80.60898333333333

Comment: I am doubtful on this `EventSpotsJoin.Spot = Links.IdLinks` condition. since for event 2054 there may be two records with different  `EventSpotsJoin.Spot` in table

Comment: Yes, now I can see it. It is true. In EventSpotsJoin table are spots with events. And they are in N:N . So, there are events and every event can have many spots. And lat long value is stored in table Links (yes strange name, it should be spot instead).

Comment: Thanx @JaydipJ - I've created view first and from this view script for joining.